# User defined type not defined error in Catia VBA

Tags: vba, catia

I'm trying to add a browse button to browse the folder.

```vb
Private Sub BrowseButton_Click()
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = “Select a File”
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFile = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Sub
```

I get

> User - defined type is not defined.

Comment: `.Title = “Select a File”` on separate line and just `with fldr`

Comment: Also, if you are really using those "curly quotes", you need to change those to normal double quotes.

Comment: Even then I'm getting that error

Comment: Which line is the error on??

Comment: Did you fix both problems? (The one I pointed out and the one Nathan pointed out)

Comment: Yes, I fixed both

Comment: It looks to me like you still have the curly quotes in your question.

Comment: You took a piece of Excel VBA code and run it in a CAD software. Does the host application really have `FileDialog`, `Application.FileDialog` and `msoFileDialogFilePicker`, which stands for *MicroSoft Office* File Dialog File Picker?

Comment: http://www.coe.org/p/fo/et/thread=24519